# I think my beta fish is sick, what should I do?

Tags: fish, diet, betta, water-changes

I've had my beta fish for about a year and a couple months ago I noticed its fins were turning a blackish colour and appear to look "fried" at the edges. Now my fish doesn't eat and I think its becoming very sick. I tried doing 50% water changes and adding water conditioner but she keeps getting worse by the day. She doesn't move often. What should I do? Please help, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you need to give a lot more information about your setup,tank size and most important all the relevant water parameters(the result of your water tests)